# Cordova iPad app – brightness randomly changes

Tags: ios, cordova, canvas, createjs

I have a simple Cordova iPad app, using a fullscreen HTML5 canvas (and the CreateJS library).

When the app is running, the screen brightness randomly changes slightly – sometimes darker, sometimes lighter. As far as I can tell, the device brightness itself is not changing (i.e the brightness slider in the iOS control center doesn't shift).

The problem doesn't occur when the app runs outside Cordova as a web app, so I believe it to be a Cordova-related issue.

Comment: Isn't it just slight brightness adjustment due to light sensor read?

Comment: I thought that at first, but it's happening with the iPad lying flat on the table with no changing light conditions around it.